# R: Merging/Match dataframes with semicolon-seperated values in the defining columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

Please apologize if this question is offendingly easy, but I am still an absulte beginner in R. I had some introduction courses. I know the basics. I can fairly well read it, but I still find myself lost.

Here is my question:
I have two dataframes, that somehow look like this.

```
Table1 <- data.frame("Name"=c("aaa","bbb-2; bbb", "ddd", "eee", "fff-2; fff"),
"Values1"= c(2, 0.5, 0.1, 3, 4))

Table2 <- data.frame ("Name"=c("aaa", "ccc", "bbb; ddd", "fff"),
"Values2"= c(5, 2, 1, NA), "Values3"= c(4, NA, 1, NA))
```

I would like to merge the dataframes by the Names columns, but in these name columns are some entries that are semicolon-seperated (e.g. "bbb-2; bbb") and some have some unnecessary additons like "-2".

In Table1, it seems if only those entries with "-2" but otherwise same names are seperated with the semicolon (e.g. "bbb-2; bbb").
In Table2 different names are seperated. (e.g "bbb; ddd")

I would like to add the values from Table2 to Table1, if either one of the semicolon-seperated values match. I want to keep all data in Table1. But not all data from in Table2. If Table1 was not enriched by data from Table2, the value should be ""/NULL, not 0.

However, I would like to avoid duplicating data by dividing the entries in seperate rows because of statistics!

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `sub` to remove those substring

```
Table1$Name <- sub("-\\d+", "", Table1$Name)
```

and then do the `merge`

```
merge(Table1, Table2, by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: OK, I guess that would work now, but what if in future data that I will get the names in Table1 are not only seperated by with semicolon when they have this "-2" addition, but are different names? (i.e. "bbb; ccc" instead of "bbb-2; bbb")

Comment: @fat2mad It wil only touch those cases where you have `bbc-2` is there.

Comment: @fat2mad If that would be the case, how would you decide which value of `Table2` should be assigned for `Table1`?

Comment: @akrun Your code does not exactly do what he asked for. He wants to `"add the values from Table2 to Table1, if either one of the semicolon-seperated values match"`. Could we do that with a temporary `strsplit`?

Comment: @ Leo P.: (1) That is a good question. I don't know if it really applies to my particular case, but to my knowledge in similar datasets the entries are ordered in priority. the first entry is the leading entry, (2) I guess it is ok to seperate the entries virtually into 2 rows for the match, as long as in the result the data are not dublicated.